# WebdriverIO - how to random click on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, ui-automation, webdriver-io

### WebdriverIO - how to random click on the page

In my login page. which is a small sized window(kind of mobile screen resolution), before I hit on login button an adhoc AD popup appears and I am unable to hit on Login button.

The before said popup has no constant property and keeps changing. The only best workaround is to click outside anywhere on the page which closes the popup.

Note - I have to perform this in a above mentioned window size and the popup is totally not visible

Comment: Why you need a random click on the page? is the position of the popup also randomly?

Comment: @hoangdv the thing is I have to run the test in a small sized browser and therefore no elements of the popup window will be visible or cannot be scrolled to. The only way to proceed is by clicking anywhere outside the popup.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
await (await $("body")).click()
```

it clicks the body element or try :

```
await (await $("body")).click()
await (await browser.getActiveElement()).click()
```

Comment: let me try and get back